# placement of "at" before "the approach"

Tags: prepositions

1. The siren signalled the approach of an ambulance.
2. Many kind of birds fly south at the approach of winter.

Both are taken from Cambridge Dictionary while I was searching the meanings of "approach".

In the first sentence no preposition has been placed before "the approach" while in the later "at" is placed before it. I cannot when to use "at" and when not to use.

Comment: Just a side note, are you 'stuck' on the word 'approach'? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything depends on the context and the verb preceding the noun considered.
*Approach* is a direct object in the first sentence.You don't have to use a preposition. *Signal* [WITH OBJECT] is used to indicate the existence or occurrence of (something) by actions or sounds.

> The Community could signal (What?) displeasure by refusing to cooperate
>
> 1.The siren signalled (What?) the approach of an ambulance.
>
> 2.Birds fly south (When?) at the approach of winter(when they feel winter coming)

*Approach* here is a part of an adverbial phrase of time.